# RegularExpression for 16 digits virtual visa cards with dash

Tags: regex

What is `Regular Expression` for 16 digits virtual visa cards with dash.
For example :

> 1234-5678-9123-4567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html) the Visa regex is

```
^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$
```

see the link for other card providers.

**UPDATE**

For the 16-character number with dashes:

```
^4[0-9]{3}(?:-[0-9]{4}){3}$
```

Comment: True. Updated the answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Thanks. Indeed, that capture was unnecessary.